# How to replace '\' with '//' in java String

Tags: java, string

For Example:

My String is:

```
C:\Users\Junaid\Documents\lesson2\lesson2\touchingRectangles\package.bluej
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
C://Users//Junaid//Documents//lesson2//lesson2//touchingRectangles//package.bluej
```

Comment: this is not how stackoverflow works. show us what you tried.

Comment: please add your code Abdul

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected result with the following code -

```
path = path.replace("\\", "//");
```

Here the backslash() needs to be escaped by a backslash, as it throws invalid sequence error.

But honestly you don't need double front slash(//) unless you're handling anything like an URL(https://). Sometimes the filepath requires double blackslash(//) for file or stream inputs; but not always.

I would suggest you to use File.Separator instead. E.g.

```
String filePath = "hello" + File.separator + "world"
```

this gives you -"hello\world"; that is far more enough for file path manipulations.

Hope this helped :)